# Change to get the current date and time in Google Sheets

Tags: javascript

I have this function in my sheets and I want to make a change,

```js
function Carregar_Apuracao_parcial_CRC() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    var sheet_lancamento = spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('CRC'), true);
    var sheet_bdl = spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Respostas Parcial'), true);
    var ultimalinhabdl = sheet_bdl.getLastRow();SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSpreadsheetTimeZone(), "EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm")
  sheet_lancamento.getRange('B4').copyTo(sheet_bdl.getRange(ultimalinhabdl+1, 1).activate(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  sheet_lancamento.getRange('O2').copyTo(sheet_bdl.getRange(ultimalinhabdl+1, 2).activate(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  sheet_lancamento.getRange('S5').copyTo(sheet_bdl.getRange(ultimalinhabdl+1, 3).activate(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  sheet_lancamento.getRange('T2').activate();
const sheet_draw = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
}
```

In the line "sheet_lancamento.getRange('O2'), the function get the info "=Now()" inputed in the cell O2. I want to change this line to get the actual date and time without using a cell with "=Now()". It's possible?

I tried some functions to get time, but never worked.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example from one of my projects, I like to use named ranges instead of A1 notation:

```
// Set the cell for the last time the trigger ran after passing the test above
ss.getSheetByName("Settings").getRange("TriggerLastRun").setValue(new Date());
```

[image]